# Multiple packages for single facebook app id for android apps

Tags: android, facebook

As we want to implement the Facebook Login feature for our android app (multiple apps) using single facebook app id.
Is there any way to support multiple packages using single facebook app id for android apps.

As we have found the documentation for IOS but there is not documentation for Android.

Whether it is possible or not???

Answer (score 0):

I think FB SDK supports a single app id only.
You should check the FB dashboard to see if it's possible - my guess is that it's not.

Comment: In Facebook developers option, there is a proper documentation for IOS but there is no any documentation for Android. Hence, I have posted the question...

Comment: can you post the link please?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting

this is for IOS. But we dont have for Android

Comment: You can use one Facebook app ID in multiple Android apps. Just use the same app ID in another app for login, sharing, and so on.

For deep linking and opening your app through notifications and other means, we only support a single package name/class name combination.

If you want multi-app support for deep linking, see App Links.